# Post Yammer praise via yammer rest api

Tags: rest, yammer

I faced with issue when I'm trying to post Yammer praise via Yammer REST API.

Before starting to write a code i tried to Post Yammer praise using Postman.
When I tried to use form-data option everything is fine and praise was created successfully
[from-data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrvx3.png).
Then i tried to use raw data(JSON) to post praise.
Headers:

Authorization: Bearer #Token;

yammer-capabilities: external-messaging,external-groups(and i've tried "external-messaging,parsed-body-only2,user-sidebar,external-groups");

**Content-Type: application/json**

```
{
    "body": "test body",
    "group_id": #groupId,
    "message_type": "praise",
    "title": "test title",
    "praise": {
        "comment": "test comment",
        "icon": "thumbsup",
        "praised_user_ids": [#PraisedUserId]
    }
}
```

and that is what i've got in response:

```
{
    "body": [
        "Please include a message"
    ],
    "code": "body_blank"
}
```

Can someone help me please with it? What JSON should it be to create praise via Yammer REST API

Answer (score 0):

Add one more param **skip_body_notification** as **true**.
[image]

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Yammer-Developer/POST-Praise-via-Yammer-API/m-p/274339/highlight/true#M471